# How does the proc/diskstats work to present that values? And for proc/stat and meminfo?

Tags: linux, unix, statistics, monitoring, proc

I am trying to get the diskstats data by same way that the file does. Is there any way to reach that values without reading that file? How the values are placed there? Is there any ".c" file that processes the data to place on diskstats? And for proc/stat and meminfo? (diskstats is my main concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There surely is a .c file and it's a part of the Linux kernel. If you really want to see how it's done you can start unwinding it e.g. from here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c?v=3.8

Reading from procfs is not the worst method to get the stats, actually that's what it's made for. But if you want you can try using the `iostat` util instead (see http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iostat1.html)